# LWJGL - A function that is not available in the current context was called

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I just started using LWJGL and OpenGL and I've run into a problem. I'm trying to figure out how to draw a simple line for a game I'm making using a game engine I found.

This is the link to the engine I'm using: https://github.com/SilverTiger/SilenceEngine

In the renderer class I tried adding this function -

```
 public void drawLine(Point point, Point point2) {

        GL11.glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.2f);
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_LINES);
        GL11.glVertex2d(point.x, point.y);
        GL11.glVertex2d(point2.x, point2.y);
        GL11.glEnd();

 }
```

The error that I get  is as follows:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007fff32b524cd, pid=3016, tid=0x0000000000002548
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_131-b11) (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.131-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [lwjgl.dll+0x124cd]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\sambu\workspace\NextGen Engine - 0.3.1\hs_err_pid3016.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
[LWJGL] A function that is not available in the current context was called. The JVM will abort execution. Inspect the crash log to find the responsible Java frames.
```

I'm very new to this and not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window being created in the engine has an OpenGL context of version 3.2.  In version 3.2, you cannot call the old, primitive draw calls.  All draw calls need to be done with vertex arrays and buffers.  Here is a tutorial on how to do this (keep in mind, this is written in C++): [Draw Your First Triangle](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/).  Here is the engine's forums on getting started (called Newbie Questions). [Forum](https://silenceengine.goharsha.com/forum/newbie-questions/%20%22Newbiew%20Questions)

Comment: Hi. I am currently learning about VAOs and VBOs. After implementing the code from the tutorial I was following, I got an error when calling glGenVertexArrays();

I want to note that I am using the LWJGL tutorial however so there may be a difference.

Comment: @pebble225 Make a question for SO.  I can't tell a thing without seeing code or what error you are getting.  Make sure you are initializing the OpenGL context correctly, though.

Comment: I solved it. It turns out that I was trying to initialize the VAOs before setting the context.